# Sort dictionary of arrays by both key and values in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dict = {
  "a": ["apple", "aeroplane", "ash"],
  "c": ["cat", "car"],
  "b": ["boy", "bit", "bee"]
}
```

I would like to sort it using swift and the result should be like this:

```
dict = {
  "a": ["aeroplane", "apple", "ash"],
  "b": ["bee", "bit", "boy"],
  "c": ["car", "cat"]
}
```

Both the keys and the values in the array should be in alphabetical order. However, I can only successfully sort the keys using .keys.sorted() and I failed to sort the array in each of the dictionary values in alphabetical order.

Comment: "I can only successfully sort the keys using .keys.sorted()"  What difference does that make?  Aren't you trying to sort the content of dict?

Comment: I would like to sort both the keys and the values. The keys of the dictionary should be a, b, c.... etc   and then the dictionary values array should be sorted as well.

Comment: You can sort the dictionary values (which are arrays), but you cannot sort the dictionary keys. A dictionary is an *unordered* collection of key/value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I just want to remark that it's a bit redundant to sort the keys of a dictionary because you check values associated with a given key, not where the value is, it makes no sense to order them.

Second about sorting the arrays inside the dictionary it's pretty easy, first you need to iterate over the dictionary using for each, then since the arrays are immutable after you call `.sorted()` you assign the result to the key associated with the value you just received.

```
var dict : [String:[String]] = [
  "a" : ["apple", "aeroplane", "ash"],
  "c" : ["cat", "car"],
  "b" : ["boy", "bit", "bee"]
]

// sort arrays inside an item of the dictionary
for (key,value) in dict {
    dict[key] = value.sorted()
}

print(dict)
```

Comment: Drop the call to enumerated since you are not using the offset.

Comment: Also, this would be easier using mapValues.

Comment: I wanted to leave him the option of using the keys if he wanted to do some extra steps

Comment: @Sultan, What do you mean by mapValues?

Comment: Dictionary has a function which is called "mapValues()", which you can use instead of the implementation above